# greatest() function in mysql returns blob

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use the greatest function of `mysql` but if i am trying to add one column from the sub queries it is returning me the `blob` value , I tried using mysql `workbench`, i also tried from `phpmyadmin` but the results are same.

Below is my sql query :

```
select greatest(pm10index,pm2index,noindex,so2index,o3index,nh3index,coindex)
from table ;
```

Here the values are fetched from some sub queries.

The issue occurs when i add `pm10index` column in the function , If this particular column `pm10index` is removed from the function it returns the highest value correctly .

Below is the value for `pm10index`

```
pm10,
       (CASE 
       when pm10 = 0   then 0
       when pm10 <=50  then pm10
       when pm10 >50  and   pm10 <=100 then pm10 
       when pm10 >100 and   pm10 <=250 then 100+(pm10-100)*0.666
       when pm10 >250 and   pm10 <=350 then 200+(pm10-250)
       when pm10 >350 and   pm10 <=430 then 300+(pm10-350)*1.25
       when pm10 >430 then  400+(pm10-430)*1.25
       END) pm10index
```

`pm10` is defined as `varchar` datatype , while all other fields are also defined as `varchar`

It will be great if you can help me here . Thanks in advance .

Comment: Maybe you should `cast` your columns as `decimals`?

Comment: Yes i wil check on this , interestingly all the columns are defined as varchar , but the issue is with only one column.

Answer (score 1):

> Below is the value for pm10index ... pm10 is defined as varchar datatype

There is no varchar (or any type of string) in the code you provided. Even if you did cast the data to a varchar, your going to end up with odd results (try `select greatest('2','100');`).

While MySQL will do its best to compare strings and numbers, sooner or later its going to break. Unless you have at least consistent data types (and really it should be correct data types) your code cannot be relied upon.